# Accessing the updated state in useEffect doesn't work

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

I need to fetch two API-endpoints in the `useEffect`call, where the second call uses the result of the first call.

So currently I have:

```js
const [steamID, setSteamID] = React.useState<string>();
const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    getLoggedInUser()
      .then((userObj) => userObj?.steamID)
      .then((fetchedSteamId) => {
        setSteamID(fetchedSteamId);
        console.log("steamID1: " + steamID);
        console.log("steamID2: " + fetchedSteamId);
      }).then(
         // second API-Call which needs steamID
         // by either using steamID(state) or fetchedSteamId(result)
      )
      .catch((err) => {
        setLoading(true);
      });
}, []);
```

I tried to append another `.then()` before the `.catch()` where I access the `steamID` state. But already with the code provided I have the following output:

```js
steamID: undefined
steamID: 1234567891011
```

So when updating my state `steamID` inside `useEffect`, it will be undefined when accessed within `useEffect` unless i make any changes with hot-reload. The second output will always be correct.

I sure could just always pass the result further down, but is this the proper way? And how can I make sure, *after* `useEffect`, my state contains the correct values?

Comment: Passing result further down is the proper way. React batches state updates and until your promise chain is not resolved there won't be a render. And your state will always contain the previous value. Only once the render has been done, state will update.

Comment: well okay if that is the proper way, as also stated by @AlexanderStaroselsky I will do it like this. Didn't feel quite right, because the code inside `useEffect` kinda looks like a mess then. But I think thats just react / typescript which I am new to. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always just pass `fetchedSteamId` to the next `then` in the promise chain and use that in whatever way you need:

```js
const [steamID, setSteamID] = React.useState<string>();
const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    getLoggedInUser()
      .then((userObj) => userObj?.steamID)
      .then((fetchedSteamId) => {
        setSteamID(fetchedSteamId);
        console.log("steamID1: " + steamID);
        console.log("steamID2: " + fetchedSteamId);
        return fetchedSteamId;
      }).then((fetchedSteamId) => {
        // use the id
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
}, []);
```

If the goal is to both set that id and use that id in another operation, it could work. Otherwise you can use another useEffect, with `steamId` as the dependency:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    getLoggedInUser()
      .then((userObj) => userObj?.steamID)
      .then((fetchedSteamId) => {
        setSteamID(fetchedSteamId);
        setLoading(false);
      }).catch(err => setLoading(false));
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  // do some operation when steamId useState value changes
}, [steamId]);
```

Comment: Wow okay, didn't expect to be able and use two `useEffect`, good to know ! And how can I be sure, that my state is set **a 100%** after `useEffect`, so in my component itself?

Comment: @codedor Note sure what you mean exactly. Do you mean how to know whether `steamId` has a value? In the component rendering, you can use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html?msclkid=d4749d78d16111ecba6ead80133715ab) to only render something based on the conditions you want.

Comment: Well you said, I can just pass the `fetchedSteamId` further down. But what I tried before was to `set`my state and use this state in the next fetch. But I realized, that when accessing the state, the new value was not set yet. This all happened inside of `useEffect`, but how can I be sure that my `state`  **is**  set after `useEffect`.. hope you understand :D